# Reliablity for devices produced with a raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, software-development

I have succesfully developed a computer vision solution on my raspberry pi. Now this solution would help a lot in the transportation area of my country and I want to start selling it. I don´t know exactly what is the best method to produce equipment with the raspberry. I was thinking only in getting a good case and with other pi boards just clone the solution and go to the market. But what about the reliablity of the device? Is it recommendable just going on with the current and conventional raspberry pi (I have heard is for educational purposes only) or should I change to another board?. The costs are not a big problem because I would produce 20 up to 50 of these things and I can pay 30 or 40 $ for each pi board. But the question is: Going on to produce an equiment based on the raspberry pi is only to produce a nice and fucntional case for the equipment? or are there other essential issues to be considered. I´d really appreciate your opinions

Thanks

W.D

Answer (score 6):

The Pi is definitely not guaranteed to work in harsh environments. Whether it's adequate for what you want to do depends on *what* you want to do, and what the downside of failure is. For example, if you want to use it to automatically unlock doors when it recognizes the face of an authorized user, your customers may or may not care if it fails to unlock, as they probably still have a key, but they would definitely hate it if a good whack on the side of the car caused the Pi to malfunction and open the doors (I won't even get into having to trust your software).

Element14, the actual makers of the Pi, will develop semi-custom Pi solutions for you. Why don't you give them a call and ask them if they can guarantee a certain performance level?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Raspberry Pi Compute Module in your solution, it can be used in a much more versatile way than regular Raspberry pi boards.

Comment: He use the RaspberryPi 2, the compute module is based on Raspberry Pi 1 I think. I guess he needs the power of the Pi2 to run his CV program. He can't use the Compute Module.

Comment: @Sapher I was thinking more of the form factor with a view to mass production. Not knowing exactly what the solution is, it could very well be ported to the CM, that is up to the OP to decide I suppose.

Comment: There's no mass production involve, he talks about 20-50. I understand your point of view.

Comment: Yes @Sapher it is not exactly mass production, I will make máximum 80 devices, the solution is about CV and other sensors, the PI Works around 70 % of the capacity. So I guess my solution could be appropiate now in the PI 2, in the future versions I will think about other boards. Thanks